# Django redirect to a template with variables

Tags: django, redirect, django-templates

I'm a beginner in django, and i made a sign up system. When a user register a new user, he'll be directed back to the sign in page template, with a `message` variable that a new user is added.

I've read that using `HttpResponseRedirect` after a successful `POST` request is recommended. So i can't use `render` as far as i know.

So how to achieve this using `HttpResponseRedirect` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this using the [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/messages/), which stores messages in the session.